# Making a local package installer

Tags: .net, windows, local, package-managers

I'm going to be building a package manager and installer for my home network, and I'm unsure of the technologies i should use. I was thinking WPF for the interface and SQL for actually storing package data, as well as some sort of scripting for configurable installation. However, i don't know if I'm missing anything. In short, here are my questions:

- What technologies are necessary to make this program?
- Is there something like this already out there?
- How much should be on the server we have and how much should go on whatever client i'm building?
- am i going about this completely the wrong way?

Notes:

- I'd like to use .NET as it's where i have most of my experience
- It will be running on Windows 7 and one or two vista/xp machines. The server is a windows home server.
- The packages will be regular installers/updates of programs such as Daemon tools, Notepad++, or 7zip. Thre are also disk image programs, as well as possibly programs with no installer as such.

Answer (score 1):

http://windows-get.sourceforge.net/index.php

Maybe you instead should just build packages for this instead? Saves you quite a bit of dev time :)

Comment: I'm making a *local* package management system, which that doesnt look like. Besides, i'd like the experience as well as something that i can add features to that i want!

Comment: @RCIX: So set up your own server and add what you want - you don't have to use their repos; if you want to have fun writing it on your own, you should do it though!

Comment: Which leads me back to the questions outlined above. ^-^